# Convert date format from DD.MM.YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: string, powershell, date

I have folders on the disk in the german format: "01.05.2019", which I want to convert into the english format: "2019-05-01".

I am using PowerShell. Is there a fancy function for doing this? Or should I get all substrings and reorder them?

Currently I only collect the strings:

```
$OrgDir = "P:\Fotos\Import"
$folders = Get-ChildItem $($OrgDir) -Directory 
foreach ($dir in $folders) {
    Write-Host "folder: " $dir
}
```

Comment: `[datetime]::Parse("01.05.2019").ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: Careful.  That could be interpreted as either January 5th or May 1st depending on the default culture setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[DateTime]::ParseExact()` to avoid the date parser mixing up the month and day:

```
$OrgDir = "P:\Fotos\Import"
$folders = Get-ChildItem $OrgDir -Directory
foreach ($dir in $folders) {
    Write-Host "folder: $([DateTime]::ParseExact($dir.Name, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))"
}
```

The above prints out the converted names. To efficiently rename the files however, I recommend this:

```
Get-ChildItem $OrgDir -Directory | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName (
            [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Name, "dd.MM.yyyy", $null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        )
    }
```

This line of PowerShell renames all directories at `$OrgDir` to the new date format, given that all directories in the folder are named this way.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

---

### UPDATE:

As @Matt Johnson pointed out, `$null` uses your system default culture for `ParseExact(string, format, culture)` (as well as `ToString(format, culture)`). This may or may not cause problems based on what culture setting your system currently has.

To ensure these settings do not interfere with this function, use `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` for the culture parameters in both `ParseExact()` and `ToString()`.

Comment: FYI, `$null` will use the current culture.  If the current culture doesn't use the Gregorian calendar system, the value could get interpreted incorrectly (example, `ar-SA` defaults to `HijriCalendar`).  Passing `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` is safer. (Same with the `ToString` method's second parameter).  Of course, if the script never runs on a machine with such settings, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

[Matt Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson) provides important pointers in his comments:

**To write robust code that works *independently of what culture is in effect*, specify the culture context *explicitly***, both when:

- parsing strings as `[datetime]` instances
- formatting `[datetime]` instances as strings

Therefore, use the following in your case:

```
PS> [datetime]::Parse('01.05.2019', [cultureinfo] 'de-DE').
      ToString('yyyy-MM-dd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
2019-05-01
```

- Since `01.05.2019` is a valid (day-first) short date in German, no custom parsing is needed, only `de-DE` (German / Germany) as the cultural context.
- `.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)` specifies an explicit output-format string; `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` - the invariant culture (based on US-English) - as the cultural context ensures that the date is interpreted based on the Gregorian calendar.

Note that in PowerShell *casts* (e.g., `[datetime] '01.05.2019'`) and *string interpolation* (e.g., `"$(get-date)"`) *always* use the *invariant culture* - whereas calling `[datetime]::Parse()` and `.ToString()` without an explicit culture (format-provider) argument uses the *current* culture.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this did the trick for me:

```
PS> [datetime]::Parse('01.05.2019', [cultureinfo] 'de-DE').
      ToString('yyyy-MM-dd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

All other solutions ended in:

> Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "15.12.2019" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Thanks a lot mklement0.